# How to Authorize a Managed Identity to access Azure Table Storage using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-managed-identity

I was using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` C# library to access my `Azure Table Storage` account using storage credentials as follows.

```
_CloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
                new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
                azureStorageAccountName, azureStorageAccountKey),
                true
            );
_CloudTableClient = _CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

However, Microsoft lately stated that it is now available to access the ATS service using `Managed Identities` ([Authorize access to tables using Azure Active Directory (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)) and they shared the following code example here on how to create the table using Managed Identity:

```
public static void CreateTable(string accountName, string tableName)
{
    // Construct the table endpoint from the arguments.
    string tableEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/",
                                                accountName);

    // Get a token credential and create a service client object for the table.
    TableClient tableClient = new TableClient(new Uri(tableEndpoint), 
                                                tableName, 
                                                new DefaultAzureCredential());

    try
    {
        // Create the table.
        tableClient.Create();

    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

This is fine but this example uses the `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient` instead of the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient` that I'm currently using, so is there any way to access the `Azure Table Storage` service using Managed Identity explicitly using the `CloudTableClient`?

Comment: I have a sample for downloading a blob with the old SDK: https://github.com/juunas11/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/blob/937da39208ebd5032c461a74082a5061f41a0894/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/Services/DemoService.cs#L42. This is in an older commit in this sample repo. Don't know if same will work for tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to create a table in Azure Table  Storage using Managed Identity with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient

```
public static async Task createTable(string accountName, string tableName)
{
            string tableEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/",accountName);
            var token = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
            var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token);
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
            var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(tableEndpoint), storageCredentials);
            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
}
```